# CSOM - get deleted site collections

Tags: csom, site-collection, getchanges

Is it possible to get a list of site collections deleted by administrators since a given timestamp using CSOM?

We can do this with deleted **sites** using the changes api, but what about **site collections**?

Powershell can do it: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spdeletedsite?view=sharepoint-pshttps://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spdeletedsite?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: I havent found any other solution than use Get-SPODeletedSites cmd

Comment: If you are a site collection administrator, you can list the site collections via Soap web service. The ones that are not listed, are the ones that are deleted. But that isn't really the best solution for many reasons.